# Airflow with KubernetesExecutor failing with Unknown error in KubernetesJobWatcher

Tags: kubernetes, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I've been trying to setup an Airflow environment on Kubernetes (v1.13.11-gke.14), with MySQL DB as metadata database and KubernetesExecutor as core executor. Bound a serviceAccount to Airflow deployment with all privileges and configured the same to `worker_service_account_name` as well. Now when I trigger Airflow , scheduler is throwing KubernetesJobWatcher Exception with the following logs,

```
[2019-12-13 04:40:40,919] {{kubernetes_executor.py:335}} ERROR - Unknown error in KubernetesJobWatcher. Failing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 313, in recv_into
    return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1840, in recv_into
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1646, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise WantReadError()
OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 752, in read_chunked
    self._update_chunk_length()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 682, in _update_chunk_length
    line = self._fp.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 576, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 326, in recv_into
    raise timeout("The read operation timed out")
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/executors/kubernetes_executor.py", line 333, in run
    self.worker_uuid, self.kube_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/executors/kubernetes_executor.py", line 357, in _run
    **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 144, in stream
    for line in iter_resp_lines(resp):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 48, in iter_resp_lines
    for seg in resp.read_chunked(decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 781, in read_chunked
    self._original_response.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 430, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='172.20.0.1', port=443): Read timed out.
Process KubernetesJobWatcher-1467:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 313, in recv_into
    return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1840, in recv_into
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1646, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise WantReadError()
OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 752, in read_chunked
    self._update_chunk_length()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 682, in _update_chunk_length
    line = self._fp.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 576, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 326, in recv_into
    raise timeout("The read operation timed out")
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/executors/kubernetes_executor.py", line 333, in run
    self.worker_uuid, self.kube_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/executors/kubernetes_executor.py", line 357, in _run
    **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 144, in stream
    for line in iter_resp_lines(resp):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 48, in iter_resp_lines
    for seg in resp.read_chunked(decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 781, in read_chunked
    self._original_response.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 430, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='172.20.0.1', port=443): Read timed out.
10.186.229.193 - - [13/Dec/2019:04:40:41 -0600] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 115845 "-" "kube-probe/1.13+"
[2019-12-13 04:40:42,838] {{kubernetes_executor.py:440}} ERROR - Error while health checking kube watcher process. Process died for unknown reasons
[2019-12-13 04:40:42,864] {{kubernetes_executor.py:344}} INFO - Event: and now my watch begins starting at resource_version: 0
10.186.229.193 - - [13/Dec/2019:04:40:48 -0600] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 115845 "-" "kube-probe/1.13+"
[2019-12-13 04:40:50 -0600] [49] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2019-12-13 04:40:50 -0600] [24285] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24285
10.186.229.193 - - [13/Dec/2019:04:40:51 -0600] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 115845 "-" "kube-probe/1.13+"
[2019-12-13 04:40:51,522] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor KubernetesExecutor
[2019-12-13 04:40:51,528] {{dagbag.py:92}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-12-13 04:40:52 -0600] [49] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2019-12-13 04:40:52 -0600] [24251] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 24251)
10.186.229.193 - - [13/Dec/2019:04:40:57 -0600] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 115845 "-" "kube-probe/1.13+"
10.186.229.193 - - [13/Dec/2019:04:41:01 -0600] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 115845 "-" "kube-probe/1.13+"
10.186.229.193 - - [13/Dec/2019:04:41:07 -0600] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 115845 "-" "kube-probe/1.13+"
10.186.229.193 - - [13/Dec/2019:04:41:11 -0600] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 115845 "-" "kube-probe/1.13+"
10.186.229.193 - - [13/Dec/2019:04:41:18 -0600] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 115845 "-" "kube-probe/1.13+"
10.186.229.193 - - [13/Dec/2019:04:41:21 -0600] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 115845 "-" "kube-probe/1.13+"
[2019-12-13 04:41:23 -0600] [49] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2019-12-13 04:41:23 -0600] [24290] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24290
[2019-12-13 04:41:24,024] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor KubernetesExecutor
[2019-12-13 04:41:24,029] {{dagbag.py:92}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2019-12-13 04:41:25 -0600] [49] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2019-12-13 04:41:25 -0600] [24256] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 24256)
10.186.229.193 - - [13/Dec/2019:04:41:27 -0600] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 115845 "-" "kube-probe/1.13+"
10.186.229.193 - - [13/Dec/2019:04:41:31 -0600] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 115845 "-" "kube-probe/1.13+"
10.186.229.193 - - [13/Dec/2019:04:41:37 -0600] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 115845 "-" "kube-probe/1.13+"
10.186.229.193 - - [13/Dec/2019:04:41:41 -0600] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 115845 "-" "kube-probe/1.13+"
[2019-12-13 04:41:42,944] {{kubernetes_executor.py:335}} ERROR - Unknown error in KubernetesJobWatcher. Failing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 313, in recv_into
    return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1840, in recv_into
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1646, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise WantReadError()
OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 752, in read_chunked
    self._update_chunk_length()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 682, in _update_chunk_length
    line = self._fp.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 576, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 326, in recv_into
    raise timeout("The read operation timed out")
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/executors/kubernetes_executor.py", line 333, in run
    self.worker_uuid, self.kube_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/executors/kubernetes_executor.py", line 357, in _run
    **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 144, in stream
    for line in iter_resp_lines(resp):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 48, in iter_resp_lines
    for seg in resp.read_chunked(decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 781, in read_chunked
    self._original_response.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 430, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='172.20.0.1', port=443): Read timed out.
Process KubernetesJobWatcher-1468:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 313, in recv_into
    return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1840, in recv_into
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1646, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise WantReadError()
OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 752, in read_chunked
    self._update_chunk_length()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 682, in _update_chunk_length
    line = self._fp.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 576, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 326, in recv_into
    raise timeout("The read operation timed out")
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/executors/kubernetes_executor.py", line 333, in run
    self.worker_uuid, self.kube_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/executors/kubernetes_executor.py", line 357, in _run
    **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 144, in stream
    for line in iter_resp_lines(resp):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 48, in iter_resp_lines
    for seg in resp.read_chunked(decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 781, in read_chunked
    self._original_response.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 430, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='172.20.0.1', port=443): Read timed out.
```

I've tried commenting `request_timeout` setting so the scheduler waits for KubernetesAPI response indefinitely as some answers suggested but the issue still persists. Would appreciate any suggestions on how to solve it.

Please find environment information as below,

```
Kubernetes Versions used: (v1.13.11-gke.14) and V1.16
Platform : GKE and Standalone VMs
Airflow Versions used: 1.10.6/1.10.5/1.10.6rc2
```

Comment: did you fix this ?